# How to hide the field names in a custom view?

Tags: views, 6

I am new to Drupal and am working on a Drupal 6 (6.28) site. I have created a custom view and corresponding block which shows the most recent story created which has been promoted to Home. The view looks great except that it displays the "Title:" and "Body:" field labels before the Title and Body. How can I remove those?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Drupal 7 with views 3 it works like this:
If you use fields as display format you can click in your field and disable the "Create a label" checkbox.

Comment: I'm using Drupal 6, so it's a bit different. But your answer did lead me down the right track. In the view's Edit mode, I had to click on the field name, then clear out the "Title" label in the "Label:" field. Thanks!